# R: cleanest way to make ten boxplots, one for each group denoted by a dummy column

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to include a boxplot for every group in a plot, but the groups are denoted by dummy columns. This plot could be drawn manually by filtering every group first separately, but this is of course not optimal. What is the most efficient method?

Data looks like this, data to be used for the boxplot is in column `Y`:

```
|  Y  | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 | etc...|
| 0.8 |    0    |    0    |    1    | ....
| 0.4 |    1    |    0    |    0    |....
```

Comment: First `pivot_longer`, then use `facet_wrap()` in your call to `ggplot2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you, though it would be helpful to have a reproducible data set to test with:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-y) %>%
  mutate(group = factor(name, unique(name))) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(value == 0, NA, y)) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(group, y)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Or, if you want them all in separate panels:

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-y) %>%
  mutate(group = factor(name, unique(name))) %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(value == 0, NA, y)) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(group, y)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(.~group, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data set created in lieu of reproducible sample**

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- cbind(data.frame(y = rnorm(100)), diag(10)[rep(1:10, each = 10),])
names(df) <- c('y', paste0('Grp', 1:10))

head(df, 20)
#>              y Grp1 Grp2 Grp3 Grp4 Grp5 Grp6 Grp7 Grp8 Grp9 Grp10
#> 1  -0.62645381    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 2   0.18364332    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 3  -0.83562861    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 4   1.59528080    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 5   0.32950777    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 6  -0.82046838    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 7   0.48742905    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 8   0.73832471    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 9   0.57578135    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 10 -0.30538839    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 11  1.51178117    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 12  0.38984324    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 13 -0.62124058    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 14 -2.21469989    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 15  1.12493092    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 16 -0.04493361    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 17 -0.01619026    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 18  0.94383621    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 19  0.82122120    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
#> 20  0.59390132    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```